# How to check the number of cores Spark uses?

Tags: apache-spark

I have `spark.cores.max` set to `24` [3 worker nodes], but If I get inside my worker node and see there is just one process [command = Java] running that consumes memory and CPU. I suspect it does not use all 8 cores (on `m2.4x large`).

How to know the number?

Answer (score 3):

You can see the number of cores occupied on each worker in the cluster under the Spark Web UI:
[image: Spark Web UI]

Comment: I'm able to see here...but my problem is..when I log into worker node and check number of processes associated with spark..it is generally just one per worker node.... I'm wondering if all my cores are utilized ?

Comment: Just trigger a parallel computation, and watch your cores load. You'll see them spike.

Comment: default port is 18080 for web UI. else accessing the machine(ssh) and then using top would give more details.

Comment: port 18080 is not for WebUI. 18080 is the default port where logs would be recorded if you start this server ($SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-history-server.sh). WebUI is started with the Spark application and binds by default on port 4040.