# Programmatically determine number of cores and amount of memory available to Spark

Tags: apache-spark

The Spark Web UI shows some interesting information about the resources available to the cluster as a whole.

[image: Spark Web UI]

I'm specifically interested in the values for:

- Workers
- Cores
- Memory

How can I query these pieces of information about the overall cluster programmatically?

Comment: There is a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25775598/877069), but I am asking specifically about programmatic access to this information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark doesn't really expose this kind of info, it's all hidden in the Master and transferred to the WebUI.

You can however use a small hack, the WebUI supports JSON by appending /json/ to a page.

So, going to `http://<master-host>:<master-port>/json/` will return just the info you're looking for:

```
{
  url: "spark://<host>:<port>",
  workers: [ ],
  cores: 0,
  coresused: 0,
  memory: 0,
  memoryused: 0,
  activeapps: [ ],
  completedapps: [ ],
  activedrivers: [ ],
  status: "ALIVE"
}
```

Comment: Marius, this is great! I imagine this must be an unstable API subject to arbitrary changes between point versions, but it will do for my purposes.

Comment: Is this still valid? Doesn't spark provide a programmatically access to this kind of information in the latest version?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well - is this still necessary or can this be done through a more official API now with Spark?

Comment: perfect answer!